# How to simulate concurrent users in JMeter if there are multiple requests in a thread group and first requests in dependent on the previous request?

Tags: performance, concurrency, jmeter

I have a load test case, where the user first request which generate token will be passed to second request and second request ID to third request. The script works fine if it is executed for 1 user where each API is run in sequential order.
To simulate concurrent users, i am setting Number of threads(users) as 10 and ramp-up as 5 seconds and loop count is 1. I am reading the user input from csv which will have 10 records of user data that will be passed to the first request to generate token.

Issue : During concurrency the correct values are not passed to the next request and ends up throwing error.
Can someone help how to overcome this issue where correct value is passed during concurrency?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual:

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

so make sure to use **variables**, not properties for passing the token.

Also if the issue is reproducible only under with high number of users it might be the case that under certain load the system stops responding properly and returning an error instead of token or something like this.

Try running your test with 2 users first and if it'll be successful start [gradually increasing the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) until the errors start occurring, this way you will know how many users your system is able to handle without errors.

You can also consider adding [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing and you're getting expected responses and [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener to save request and response data when error occurs so you could analyze it and get to the bottom of the problem